# Format float in golang html/template

Tags: go, format, go-html-template

I want to format `float64` value to 2 decimal places in golang `html/template` say in `index.html` file. In `.go` file I can format like:

```
strconv.FormatFloat(value, 'f', 2, 32)
```

But I don't know how to format it in template. I am using `gin-gonic/gin` framework for backend. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You have many options:

- You may decide to format the number e.g. using [`fmt.Sprintf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf) before passing it to the template execution (`n1`)
- Or you may create your own type where you define the `String() string` method, formatting to your liking. This is checked and used by the template engine (`n2`).
- You may also call `printf` directly and explicitly from the template and use custom format string (`n3`).
- Even though you can call `printf` directly, this requires to pass the format `string`. If you don't want to do this every time, you can register a custom function doing just that (`n4`)

See this example:

```
type MyFloat float64

func (mf MyFloat) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%.2f", float64(mf))
}

func main() {
    t := template.Must(template.New("").Funcs(template.FuncMap{
        "MyFormat": func(f float64) string { return fmt.Sprintf("%.2f", f) },
    }).Parse(templ))
    m := map[string]interface{}{
        "n0": 3.1415,
        "n1": fmt.Sprintf("%.2f", 3.1415),
        "n2": MyFloat(3.1415),
        "n3": 3.1415,
        "n4": 3.1415,
    }
    if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, m); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}

const templ = `
Number:         n0 = {{.n0}}
Formatted:      n1 = {{.n1}}
Custom type:    n2 = {{.n2}}
Calling printf: n3 = {{printf "%.2f" .n3}}
MyFormat:       n4 = {{MyFormat .n4}}`
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/fJ2hNdmHzd)):

```
Number:         n0 = 3.1415
Formatted:      n1 = 3.14
Custom type:    n2 = 3.14
Calling printf: n3 = 3.14
MyFormat:       n4 = 3.14
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But how can I format in template itself? Is there any way to format? Or I have to pass custom type too to the template with other data? Please help.

Comment: @user29 See the `n4` case: a "pure" number of type `float64` is passed (`3.1415`), and it is formatted in the tempalte: `{{printf "%.2f" .n4}}`.

Comment: 5th option: use a sub-template: `{{define "FloatFmt"}}{{printf "%.2f" .}}{{end}}` and use it with `{{template "FloatFmt"}}`. You have to wrap the call with a `{{with}}` block if the value is not `.`: `{{with .n0}}{{template "FloatFmt"}}{{end}}`).

Comment: @dolmen Good tip. About the `{{template}}` action: `{{template "name"}}` executes the template with `nil` data, but you can pass any data to it, e.g. `{{template "name" .n0}}`, so no need to wrap with `{{with}}`. Although, I think executing another template has worse performance than just calling a function.

Answer (score 15):

Use the `printf` [template built-in function](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Functions) with the `"%.2f" format`:

```
tmpl := template.Must(template.New("test").Parse(`The formatted value is = {{printf "%.2f" .}}`))

tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, 123.456789)
```

[Go Playgroung](https://play.golang.org/p/6MuYKrl7VR)

Answer (score 4):

You can register a `FuncMap`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

type Tpl struct {
    Value float64
}

func main() {
    funcMap := template.FuncMap{
        "FormatNumber": func(value float64) string {
            return fmt.Sprintf("%.2f", value)
        },
    }

    tmpl, _ := template.New("test").Funcs(funcMap).Parse(string("The formatted value is = {{ .Value | FormatNumber  }}"))

    tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, Tpl{Value: 123.45678})
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/_Rl7Ygmkw_)

Comment: There is a already a `printf` built-in function. See my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: I was wrong about rounding/truncating.

<strike>The problem with `%.2f` formatting is that it does not round but truncates.</strike>

I've developed a decimal class based on int64 for handling money that is handling floats, string parsing, JSON, etc.

It stores amount as 64 bit integer number of cents. Can be easily created from float or converted back to float.

Handy for storing in DB as well.

https://github.com/strongo/decimal

```
package example

import "github.com/strongo/decimal"

func Example() {
    var amount decimal.Decimal64p2; print(amount)  // 0
    
    amount = decimal.NewDecimal64p2(0, 43); print(amount)  // 0.43
    amount = decimal.NewDecimal64p2(1, 43); print(amount)  // 1.43
    amount = decimal.NewDecimal64p2FromFloat64(23.100001); print(amount)  // 23.10
    amount, _ = decimal.ParseDecimal64p2("2.34"); print(amount)  // 2.34
    amount, _ = decimal.ParseDecimal64p2("-3.42"); print(amount)  // -3.42
}
```