# html/template is not showing a float value with e+07 notation in exact decimal places

Tags: go, floating-point, go-templates

I'm trying an example where I'm passing a value `1.8e+07` to the `TestVal` field of struct `Student`. Now I want this `1.8e+07` value to be in exact decimal places but it is not doing so. It is able to show the value in exact decimal places(`180000`) if the value is `1.8e+05`. But if it is greater than `e+05` then it is unable to show it.

**Example**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "text/template"
    
)

// declaring a struct
type Student struct {
    Name  string
    TestVal float32
}

// main function
func main() {

    std1 := Student{"AJ", 1.8e+07}

    // "Parse" parses a string into a template
    tmp1 := template.Must(template.New("Template_1").Parse("Hello {{.Name}}, value is {{.TestVal}}"))

    // standard output to print merged data
    err := tmp1.Execute(os.Stdout, std1)

    // if there is no error,
    // prints the output
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's just the default formatting for floating point numbers. The package doc of [`fmt`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt) explains it: The `%v` verb is the default format, which for floating numbers means / reverts to `%g` which is

> `%e` for large exponents, `%f` otherwise. Precision is discussed below.

If you don't want the default formatting, use the `printf` template function and specify the format you want, for example:

```
{{printf "%f" .TestVal}}
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/ivI8KMr1h6v)):

```
Hello AJ, value is 18000000.000000
```

Or use:

```
{{printf "%.0f" .TestVal}}
```

Which will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/W2hEZby83wl)):

```
Hello AJ, value is 18000000
```

See related:

[Format float in golang html/template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41159492/format-float-in-golang-html-template/41159739#41159739)